# Creating Directed edges javafx

Tags: javafx

Currently, I have a working implementation of an undirected graph where vertices are represented as StackPanes and edges are represented as Lines. The StackPanes are draggable and when dragged the lines move accordingly.

This is what it looks like so far.

[image: This is what it looks like.]

However, I am really struggling with implementing directed graphs. Undirected graphs only really need 1 line, but with directed graphs, you will need 2 lines when there is an edge from A to B and an edge from B to A.

I want something like this when there are 2 edges between a vertex:

[image]

This is how I binded the undirected lines between 2 vertices (ie A Line between 2 StackPanes):

```
Line line = new Line();
line.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
line.setFill(null);
line.setStrokeWidth(2);
line.startXProperty().bind(vertexClickedOn.layoutXProperty().add(vertexClickedOn.translateXProperty()).add(vertexClickedOn.widthProperty().divide(2)));
line.startYProperty().bind(vertexClickedOn.layoutYProperty().add(vertexClickedOn.translateYProperty()).add(vertexClickedOn.heightProperty().divide(2)));
line.endXProperty().bind(vertexTo.layoutXProperty().add(vertexTo.translateXProperty()).add(vertexTo.widthProperty().divide(2)));
line.endYProperty().bind(vertexTo.layoutYProperty().add(vertexTo.translateYProperty()).add(vertexTo.heightProperty().divide(2)));
```

VertexClickedOn and VertexTo are both StackPanes, in graph terms, VertexClickedOn is where the edge starts and VertexTo is where the edge ends

I've been stuck on this for a while now any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, lets discuss your requirement in terms of vectors.

- You have a line (joining the centers of two circles).
- You want to place a node(arrow) at partical point on a line.
- And this point is always located at a distance of (totalLineLength - circleRadius) for end arrow and a distance of circleRadius for start arrow.
- Finally for directed lines, you want to translate this line up or down based on direction.

So once you have the line start and end points, using little Math you can get the point on a line at a certain distance. To keep the arrow direction correctly you can rotate the arrow based on the line slope.

As the code is a bit verbose because of calculations, please find below a working demo of what I mentioned above.

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.binding.BooleanBinding;
import javafx.beans.binding.DoubleBinding;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class PaneLayoutDemo extends Application {
    double sceneX, sceneY, layoutX, layoutY;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.setPadding(new Insets(20));

        Pane pane = new Pane();
        root.getChildren().add(pane);
        Scene sc = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        stage.setScene(sc);
        stage.show();

        StackPane dotA = getDot("green", "A");
        StackPane dotB = getDot("red", "B");
        StackPane dotC = getDot("yellow", "C");
        StackPane dotD = getDot("pink", "D");
        StackPane dotE = getDot("silver", "E");


        buildSingleDirectionalLine(dotA, dotB, pane, true, true); // A <--> B
        buildSingleDirectionalLine(dotB, dotC, pane, true, true); // B <--> C
        buildSingleDirectionalLine(dotC, dotD, pane, true, false); // C --> D

        // D <===> E
        buildBiDirectionalLine(true, dotD, dotE, pane);
        buildBiDirectionalLine(false, dotD, dotE, pane);

        pane.getChildren().addAll(dotA, dotB, dotC, dotD, dotE);
    }

    /**
     * Builds the single directional line with pointing arrows at each end.
     * @param startDot Pane for considering start point
     * @param endDot   Pane for considering end point
     * @param parent Parent container
     * @param hasEndArrow Specifies whether to show arrow towards end
     * @param hasStartArrow Specifies whether to show arrow towards start
     */
    private void buildSingleDirectionalLine(StackPane startDot, StackPane endDot, Pane parent, boolean hasEndArrow, boolean hasStartArrow) {
        Line line = getLine(startDot, endDot);
        StackPane arrowAB = getArrow(true, line, startDot, endDot);
        if (!hasEndArrow) {
            arrowAB.setOpacity(0);
        }
        StackPane arrowBA = getArrow(false, line, startDot, endDot);
        if (!hasStartArrow) {
            arrowBA.setOpacity(0);
        }
        StackPane weightAB = getWeight(line);
        parent.getChildren().addAll(line, weightAB, arrowBA, arrowAB);
    }

    /**
     * Builds the bi directional line with pointing arrow at specified end.
     * @param isEnd Specifies whether the line is towards end or not. If false then the line is towards start.
     * @param startDot Pane for considering start point
     * @param endDot   Pane for considering end point
     * @param parent Parent container
     */
    private void buildBiDirectionalLine(boolean isEnd, StackPane startDot, StackPane endDot, Pane parent) {
        Line virtualCenterLine = getLine(startDot, endDot);
        virtualCenterLine.setOpacity(0);
        StackPane centerLineArrowAB = getArrow(true, virtualCenterLine, startDot, endDot);
        centerLineArrowAB.setOpacity(0);
        StackPane centerLineArrowBA = getArrow(false, virtualCenterLine, startDot, endDot);
        centerLineArrowBA.setOpacity(0);

        Line directedLine = new Line();
        directedLine.setStroke(Color.RED);
        directedLine.setStrokeWidth(2);

        double diff = isEnd ? -centerLineArrowAB.getPrefWidth() / 2 : centerLineArrowAB.getPrefWidth() / 2;
        final ChangeListener<Number> listener = (obs, old, newVal) -> {
            Rotate r = new Rotate();
            r.setPivotX(virtualCenterLine.getStartX());
            r.setPivotY(virtualCenterLine.getStartY());
            r.setAngle(centerLineArrowAB.getRotate());
            Point2D point = r.transform(new Point2D(virtualCenterLine.getStartX(), virtualCenterLine.getStartY() + diff));
            directedLine.setStartX(point.getX());
            directedLine.setStartY(point.getY());

            Rotate r2 = new Rotate();
            r2.setPivotX(virtualCenterLine.getEndX());
            r2.setPivotY(virtualCenterLine.getEndY());
            r2.setAngle(centerLineArrowBA.getRotate());
            Point2D point2 = r2.transform(new Point2D(virtualCenterLine.getEndX(), virtualCenterLine.getEndY() - diff));
            directedLine.setEndX(point2.getX());
            directedLine.setEndY(point2.getY());
        };
        centerLineArrowAB.rotateProperty().addListener(listener);
        centerLineArrowBA.rotateProperty().addListener(listener);
        virtualCenterLine.startXProperty().addListener(listener);
        virtualCenterLine.startYProperty().addListener(listener);
        virtualCenterLine.endXProperty().addListener(listener);
        virtualCenterLine.endYProperty().addListener(listener);

        StackPane mainArrow = getArrow(isEnd, directedLine, startDot, endDot);
        parent.getChildren().addAll(virtualCenterLine, centerLineArrowAB, centerLineArrowBA, directedLine, mainArrow);
    }

    /**
     * Builds a line between the provided start and end panes center point.
     *
     * @param startDot Pane for considering start point
     * @param endDot   Pane for considering end point
     * @return Line joining the layout center points of the provided panes.
     */
    private Line getLine(StackPane startDot, StackPane endDot) {
        Line line = new Line();
        line.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
        line.setStrokeWidth(2);
        line.startXProperty().bind(startDot.layoutXProperty().add(startDot.translateXProperty()).add(startDot.widthProperty().divide(2)));
        line.startYProperty().bind(startDot.layoutYProperty().add(startDot.translateYProperty()).add(startDot.heightProperty().divide(2)));
        line.endXProperty().bind(endDot.layoutXProperty().add(endDot.translateXProperty()).add(endDot.widthProperty().divide(2)));
        line.endYProperty().bind(endDot.layoutYProperty().add(endDot.translateYProperty()).add(endDot.heightProperty().divide(2)));
        return line;
    }

    /**
     * Builds an arrow on the provided line pointing towards the specified pane.
     *
     * @param toLineEnd Specifies whether the arrow to point towards end pane or start pane.
     * @param line      Line joining the layout center points of the provided panes.
     * @param startDot  Pane which is considered as start point of line
     * @param endDot    Pane which is considered as end point of line
     * @return Arrow towards the specified pane.
     */
    private StackPane getArrow(boolean toLineEnd, Line line, StackPane startDot, StackPane endDot) {
        double size = 12; // Arrow size
        StackPane arrow = new StackPane();
        arrow.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#333333;-fx-border-width:1px;-fx-border-color:black;-fx-shape: \"M0,-4L4,0L0,4Z\"");//
        arrow.setPrefSize(size, size);
        arrow.setMaxSize(size, size);
        arrow.setMinSize(size, size);

        // Determining the arrow visibility unless there is enough space between dots.
        DoubleBinding xDiff = line.endXProperty().subtract(line.startXProperty());
        DoubleBinding yDiff = line.endYProperty().subtract(line.startYProperty());
        BooleanBinding visible = (xDiff.lessThanOrEqualTo(size).and(xDiff.greaterThanOrEqualTo(-size)).and(yDiff.greaterThanOrEqualTo(-size)).and(yDiff.lessThanOrEqualTo(size))).not();
        arrow.visibleProperty().bind(visible);

        // Determining the x point on the line which is at a certain distance.
        DoubleBinding tX = Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
            double xDiffSqu = (line.getEndX() - line.getStartX()) * (line.getEndX() - line.getStartX());
            double yDiffSqu = (line.getEndY() - line.getStartY()) * (line.getEndY() - line.getStartY());
            double lineLength = Math.sqrt(xDiffSqu + yDiffSqu);
            double dt;
            if (toLineEnd) {
                // When determining the point towards end, the required distance is total length minus (radius + arrow half width)
                dt = lineLength - (endDot.getWidth() / 2) - (arrow.getWidth() / 2);
            } else {
                // When determining the point towards start, the required distance is just (radius + arrow half width)
                dt = (startDot.getWidth() / 2) + (arrow.getWidth() / 2);
            }

            double t = dt / lineLength;
            double dx = ((1 - t) * line.getStartX()) + (t * line.getEndX());
            return dx;
        }, line.startXProperty(), line.endXProperty(), line.startYProperty(), line.endYProperty());

        // Determining the y point on the line which is at a certain distance.
        DoubleBinding tY = Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
            double xDiffSqu = (line.getEndX() - line.getStartX()) * (line.getEndX() - line.getStartX());
            double yDiffSqu = (line.getEndY() - line.getStartY()) * (line.getEndY() - line.getStartY());
            double lineLength = Math.sqrt(xDiffSqu + yDiffSqu);
            double dt;
            if (toLineEnd) {
                dt = lineLength - (endDot.getHeight() / 2) - (arrow.getHeight() / 2);
            } else {
                dt = (startDot.getHeight() / 2) + (arrow.getHeight() / 2);
            }
            double t = dt / lineLength;
            double dy = ((1 - t) * line.getStartY()) + (t * line.getEndY());
            return dy;
        }, line.startXProperty(), line.endXProperty(), line.startYProperty(), line.endYProperty());

        arrow.layoutXProperty().bind(tX.subtract(arrow.widthProperty().divide(2)));
        arrow.layoutYProperty().bind(tY.subtract(arrow.heightProperty().divide(2)));

        DoubleBinding endArrowAngle = Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
            double stX = toLineEnd ? line.getStartX() : line.getEndX();
            double stY = toLineEnd ? line.getStartY() : line.getEndY();
            double enX = toLineEnd ? line.getEndX() : line.getStartX();
            double enY = toLineEnd ? line.getEndY() : line.getStartY();
            double angle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(enY - stY, enX - stX));
            if (angle < 0) {
                angle += 360;
            }
            return angle;
        }, line.startXProperty(), line.endXProperty(), line.startYProperty(), line.endYProperty());
        arrow.rotateProperty().bind(endArrowAngle);

        return arrow;
    }

    /**
     * Builds a pane at the center of the provided line.
     *
     * @param line Line on which the pane need to be set.
     * @return Pane located at the center of the provided line.
     */
    private StackPane getWeight(Line line) {
        double size = 20;
        StackPane weight = new StackPane();
        weight.setStyle("-fx-background-color:grey;-fx-border-width:1px;-fx-border-color:black;");
        weight.setPrefSize(size, size);
        weight.setMaxSize(size, size);
        weight.setMinSize(size, size);

        DoubleBinding wgtSqrHalfWidth = weight.widthProperty().divide(2);
        DoubleBinding wgtSqrHalfHeight = weight.heightProperty().divide(2);
        DoubleBinding lineXHalfLength = line.endXProperty().subtract(line.startXProperty()).divide(2);
        DoubleBinding lineYHalfLength = line.endYProperty().subtract(line.startYProperty()).divide(2);

        weight.layoutXProperty().bind(line.startXProperty().add(lineXHalfLength.subtract(wgtSqrHalfWidth)));
        weight.layoutYProperty().bind(line.startYProperty().add(lineYHalfLength.subtract(wgtSqrHalfHeight)));
        return weight;
    }

    /**
     * Builds a pane consisting of circle with the provided specifications.
     *
     * @param color Color of the circle
     * @param text  Text inside the circle
     * @return Draggable pane consisting a circle.
     */
    private StackPane getDot(String color, String text) {
        double radius = 50;
        double paneSize = 2 * radius;
        StackPane dotPane = new StackPane();
        Circle dot = new Circle();
        dot.setRadius(radius);
        dot.setStyle("-fx-fill:" + color + ";-fx-stroke-width:2px;-fx-stroke:black;");

        Label txt = new Label(text);
        txt.setStyle("-fx-font-size:18px;-fx-font-weight:bold;");
        dotPane.getChildren().addAll(dot, txt);
        dotPane.setPrefSize(paneSize, paneSize);
        dotPane.setMaxSize(paneSize, paneSize);
        dotPane.setMinSize(paneSize, paneSize);
        dotPane.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
            sceneX = e.getSceneX();
            sceneY = e.getSceneY();
            layoutX = dotPane.getLayoutX();
            layoutY = dotPane.getLayoutY();
        });

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> dotOnMouseDraggedEventHandler = e -> {
            // Offset of drag
            double offsetX = e.getSceneX() - sceneX;
            double offsetY = e.getSceneY() - sceneY;

            // Taking parent bounds
            Bounds parentBounds = dotPane.getParent().getLayoutBounds();

            // Drag node bounds
            double currPaneLayoutX = dotPane.getLayoutX();
            double currPaneWidth = dotPane.getWidth();
            double currPaneLayoutY = dotPane.getLayoutY();
            double currPaneHeight = dotPane.getHeight();

            if ((currPaneLayoutX + offsetX < parentBounds.getWidth() - currPaneWidth) && (currPaneLayoutX + offsetX > -1)) {
                // If the dragNode bounds is within the parent bounds, then you can set the offset value.
                dotPane.setTranslateX(offsetX);
            } else if (currPaneLayoutX + offsetX < 0) {
                // If the sum of your offset and current layout position is negative, then you ALWAYS update your translate to negative layout value
                // which makes the final layout position to 0 in mouse released event.
                dotPane.setTranslateX(-currPaneLayoutX);
            } else {
                // If your dragNode bounds are outside parent bounds,ALWAYS setting the translate value that fits your node at end.
                dotPane.setTranslateX(parentBounds.getWidth() - currPaneLayoutX - currPaneWidth);
            }

            if ((currPaneLayoutY + offsetY < parentBounds.getHeight() - currPaneHeight) && (currPaneLayoutY + offsetY > -1)) {
                dotPane.setTranslateY(offsetY);
            } else if (currPaneLayoutY + offsetY < 0) {
                dotPane.setTranslateY(-currPaneLayoutY);
            } else {
                dotPane.setTranslateY(parentBounds.getHeight() - currPaneLayoutY - currPaneHeight);
            }
        };
        dotPane.setOnMouseDragged(dotOnMouseDraggedEventHandler);
        dotPane.setOnMouseReleased(e -> {
            // Updating the new layout positions
            dotPane.setLayoutX(layoutX + dotPane.getTranslateX());
            dotPane.setLayoutY(layoutY + dotPane.getTranslateY());

            // Resetting the translate positions
            dotPane.setTranslateX(0);
            dotPane.setTranslateY(0);
        });
        return dotPane;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```